# How to use select2.js and select.css for Activedropdown list - YiiFramework

Tags: yii, jquery-select2

How to use select2.js and select2.css  for dropdownlist widget in yiiframework.
I have tried to use like this,

http://jsbin.com/edeseh/2/edit

but its not working for me i am getting this listbox look and feel. how to use this ?

[image]

Comment: it looks ok to me on your link

Comment: but its not working only ordinary listbox cuming, not that look and feel

Comment: added screen capture below

Answer (score 0):

for your comment, here is the answer, I see it working as expected, screen capture from your link

[image]

Comment: Please see updated post, i am getting that look and feel for listbox.

Comment: you may not have access to either a JS or CSS link, you can be behind some firewall which might be preventing this, or javascript might have been disabled in your browser, try to access JS and CSS links using browser